# Hose timer is it bad for spigot and pipes?

Tags: hose

We just had new landscaping put in and need to use a drip hose for the next few weeks. We have a timer to go for :30 mins at 7:30am and then again at 7:30 pm. My question is  “won’t the water pressure build to the point where it could damage the pipes or spigot? What happens to the water in the 12 hours between time settings? Thank you for your time.

Comment: The hose spigot has a valve. It spends most of its time shut off. You're just adding another valve that spends most of its time shut off. The pressure cannot rise above the incoming pressure to your house, whcih is the pressure normally on your pipes when valves are closed.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing to worry about. The same water pressure that is in water pipes without the timer is in your pipes with the timer. All the components are designed to work under normal household water pressures without rupturing.

Comment: RetiredATC greatly appreciate your answer.